# Like & Comment Button then save it to parse

Tags: ios, ios7

Does anyone knows how to implement these buttons under tableview footer then save it and retreive to parse?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *cellidentifier=@"footer";
    UITableViewCell *footer = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIView* FView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 100.0)];
    UIButton *like = (UIButton *)[footer viewWithTag:1];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonwastapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [FView addSubview:self.like];
    return [FView autorelease];
}

- (void)buttonwastapped:(UIButton*)sender
   {

    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"likes"];
    [relation addObject:post];
    [user saveInBackground];

} //i try to use that but nothing happened
```

Comment: Is the button in the footer? And if so, is `buttonwastapped:` being called when that button's selected?

Comment: yeah it is being called

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add buttons to footer view of section create a button (like or comment ) in view for footer and add target. it seems that your are allocating button some where else. theres no use to retrive uitableview cell.here is the sample code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView* FView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 100.0)];
    UIButton *likeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    likeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 40); // set your btn frame
    [likeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonwastapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [FView addSubView:likeBtn];

    return [FView autorelease];
}
```